# Distance difference when moving longitude in maps services

Tags: python, google-maps, bing-maps, mercator

I try to get two juxtaposed tiles in maps services like Google Maps or Bing Maps at a given zoom level (20 in my case). I managed to do it with those methods:

```
def meters_per_pixel_NS(lat, zoom): 
    return 156543.03392 * math.cos(math.radians(lat)) / 2**zoom

def meters_per_pixel_EW(zoom):
    return 156543.03392 / 2**zoom

def get_next_coord(coord, dist):
    K = 1852*60 # 1 nautical mile  = 1852 m; multiplied by 60 to get degrees
    delta = dist/K
    return coord + delta
```

Let's say I have the following tile of 256 pixels, captured in 59.329411, 18.059484 somewhere in Stockolm and the following tile that would be juxtaposed on the right, captured in 59.329411, 18.05982793911214

[image: 59.329411, 18.059484]

[image: 59.329411, 18.05982793911214]

According to my method `meters_per_pixel_EW(zoom)`, the distance from the left border to the right border (which is also the shifting) is 38.22 meters. It is a constant that does not depend on the latitude and which is wrong, because it is actually 19.57 meters wide, just like the value I would get if I did a vertical shifting (that depends on the latitude).

That seems logical, because otherwise the image would be completely distored (a height of 19.57 meters and a width of 38.22 meters).

And yet, I managed to obtain the correct coordinates for the next tile by converting 38.22 meters in degrees. Again, it seems logical as the mercator projection does not distort the longitudes.

In short, I asked a shifting of 38.22 meters and I received a shifting of 19.57 meters. If I did the same in Mexico, I would ask the exact same shifting (in degrees) and get a higher horizontal distance.

I checked both on Google Maps and Bing Maps, it works. How can I explain this "paradox"? Is there something I don't understand in Mercator projection or is there a transformations/corrections that is made by maps services ?

Comment: Longitudes are highly distorted in 3857. A degree of longitude near the pole has the same "width" in  3857 as a degree of longitude at the equator, while in reality near the pole a degree is a few centimeters wide only

Comment: @JGH is correct see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#/media/File:Tissot_mercator.png (Tissot's indicatrix) for a visual of this issue.

Comment: Okay, I see, the distance I actually got with my two methods is actually the distance I have on this projection. As the North Pole is awalys at the top, the horizontal shifting is always the same on the projection, but is completely different in reality. Thanks for your help!